# Beamer poster theorem style without boxes

Tags: beamer, theorems

I'm making a poster using `beamer` and when I use `\begin{theorem}` and `\begin{proof}` it makes the theorems and proofs in a box just like a block title would be.

I understand this is the default setting when using `beamer` but I want my theorems and proofs to look like the default when just writing an article in LaTeX. Is there a way I can change the theorem style or `theorem` environment so that `theorem` and `proof` are no longer in boxes?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671839/beamer-poster-theorem-style-without-boxes?noredirect=1) was migrated here from [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/). Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 5):

The style is defined by

- `\setbeamertemplate{theorem begin}` and
- `\setbeamertemplate{theorem end}`

Check page 122 of [`beameruserguide.pdf`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf). In the following I have just deleted the `\inserttheoremblockenv` commands from the definition in the manual.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usetheme{boadilla}
\setbeamertemplate{theorem begin}{{
\inserttheoremheadfont
\inserttheoremname
\inserttheoremnumber
\ifx\inserttheoremaddition\@empty\else\ (\inserttheoremaddition)\fi%
\inserttheorempunctuation
}}
\setbeamertemplate{theorem end}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{theorem}
Hello World!
\end{theorem}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For what it's worth, in order to avoid getting Theorem 1 (), I need to use `\empty` and not `\@empty`.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a naive approach at defining your own `mytheorem` and `myproof` environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\newenvironment<>{mytheorem}[1][]
  {\alert{\upshape\textbf{Theorem}} #1\hspace*{\fill} \\
   \itshape}
  {}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment<>{myproof}[1][\proofname]{%
  \par
  \def\insertproofname{#1\@addpunct{.}}%
  \pushQED{\qed}
  \alert{\textbf{\insertproofname}} \hspace*{\fill} \\}
{\popQED}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{This is a frame title}
  \begin{theorem}
    This is a theorem statement.
  \end{theorem}

  \begin{proof}
    This is a theorem proof.
  \end{proof}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{This is a frame title}
  \begin{mytheorem}
    This is a theorem statement.
  \end{mytheorem}

  \begin{myproof}
    This is a theorem proof.
  \end{myproof}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

In the above example, `mytheorem` typesets `Theorem` using in **boldface**, upright and "alerted" font (`\alert{\upshape\textbf{...}}`) just to show that there is freedom in the formatting. The same goes for `myproof`.

It would be possible to *completely* duplicate the `theorem` environment that would allow (1) a bracketed optional argument and (2) even a theorem number, if needed. However, since this still forms part of a presentation where numbering doesn't make much sense, it's been left out. At the moment, specifying an optional parenthesized theorem addition is obtain using `\begin{mytheorem}[(...)]`.

Defining your own, new environment for theorems and proofs allows you to switch between or back to the regular `theorem` and `proof` environments, if needed.